# how to use function in c# that using window form from typescript?

Tags: c#, angular, winforms, typescript

I have a code that is based on c# using web browser.
what i'm doing is change javascript code in web browser to angular7 and typescript

here is c# code and javascript to use c# function from javascript

in c#

```
  public int CheckLogin(object phone, object password)
```

in javascript

```
  window.external.CheckLogin(number,password)
```

it was easy to use CheckLogin Fuction from javascript using window.external.[method]

but in typescript the windows.external.CheckLogin says

```
    "Property 'CheckLogin' does not exist on type 'External'"
```

How can I use c# function from web using angular7 or typescript?

Comment: You should be able to create interface in Typescript to "mimic" External.

Comment: You can't just simply convert the code. If you want to check if the user is logged, in angular, you can achieve it using `AuthGuard` and an httpCall in a service to your BE.

Comment: @user7254859: angular purpose is not "to change javascript code". I think you don't understand what you're trying to do, try to calirfy your goal first.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the type information for this, you can extend the `External` interface used by `window.external`:

```
interface External {
    CheckLogin(num: number, pw: string);
}

window.external.CheckLogin(1, 'password');
```

If you want to actually call server-side C# code from the client, you'll need to perform a fetch to an endpoint that runs the server-side code!